# Search Each Word Of a Search Using PHP MYSQL Search Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I want to fetching Records On the Basis Of Entered Keywords in the Search Bar.
Suppose I have Below 3 Records in My SQL Table's Column

1. Beautiful Small Kid.
2. Beautiful Rabbit in the Zoo.
3. Natural Water.

Now, If the Search Query contains `Beautiful`, It will Return First 2 Records.
If the Search Query contains `Beautiful (anything)`, It will Return Nothing.

I want those First 2 Records to be Displayed in this case too, Because It has the same word `beautiful` like in above searched Query.

Right Now, I am Using
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%value%' ORDER BY id ASC`

Is there any Other Query or Method to Achieve Such Sort Of Results ?

Comment: `LIKE 'value%'` ought to fix this or use a case insensitive method.

Comment: Not Working Bro.

Comment: you've an answer below; see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (name LIKE '%value1%') OR (name LIKE '%value2%') ORDER BY id ASC`

etc

So, you would have to split up your search string into separate words.

```
$str = yourinput;
$strarray = (explode(" ",$str));
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
Foreach($strarray as $key=>$value){
If($key > 0){
$query = $query . "OR";
}
$query = $query . " (name LIKE '%" . $value . "%') ";
}
$query = $query . "ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Comment: Bro, Thanks for Your Answer.
Bro, Tell me If a User wrote Beautiful (something) then what will be the php condition on the basis of above query will wrote ?
means If a User wrote only single word then ?
and if someone wrote multiple words then ?

Comment: There are different ways of approaching the problem.

If a user enters more than one keyword you need to split them up, perhaps into an array. Then you could add `OR` clauses for each keyword, or run multiple queries for each keyword adding the results to an array, which is your output.

Comment: Perhaps this will point you in the right direction
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Comment: Can Any One Among You :)
Kindly Write a Short Code For Me Please.

Comment: I've added a possible solution to my answer.

Comment: Bro it saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in index.php on line 22

Comment: You also need to sanitize user input first to prevent sql injection. You'll find a thread on that somewhere else on stackoverflow if you search for it.

Comment: Try it again now, I missed a ";".

Comment: You also missed AND i think so.
Where it should placed now :(

Comment: Thank you So Much Bro :)
Really Helpfull :)
Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. I think it should be `OR` rather than `AND`, as you're looking for either word to be present not both. Anyway, good luck with it!

Comment: I was looking for this Query Exactly 
Thanks Bro :)

Comment: I think it's better to use AND than OR