# Search Each Word Of a Search string Using PHP mysqli bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli

I want PHP to search for each word in string in MySQL database using MySQLi and `bind_param()`

If the search string is `some word`, PHP search for `some` and `word`

I found this answer 
[Search Each Word Of a Search Using PHP MYSQL Search Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859803/search-each-word-of-a-search-using-php-mysql-search-query)
but I can't use it with MySQLi and `bind_param()`

This is my code:

```
if (!empty($search)) {
    $search = "%{$search}%";
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE hospname LIKE ?");
    $sql->bind_param("s",$search);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    $sql->close();
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any problems? What is reason for this post?

Comment: I need it to search for each word separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner solution

```
$search_arr = explode(" ",$search);
$params = [];
$where = [];

foreach($search_arr as $word)
{
    $where[] = "hospname like ?";
    $params[] = "%$word%";
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE ".implode($where, " or ");
$sql = $conn->prepare($query);

$sql->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($params)), ...$params);
$sql->execute();

$result = $sql->get_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
if (!empty($search)) {
$search = explode(" ",$search);


$query="SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE hospname";
$params=array();
$params_type="";

foreach($search as $word)
{

    $query.=" like ? or hospname";
    $params_type.='s';

}

$params[]=& $params_type;

$query=rtrim($query, 'or hospname');
$sql = $conn->prepare($query);




foreach($search as $word)
{

    $search_word="%{$word}%";
    $params[]=& $search_word;

}
call_user_func_array(array($sql,'bind_param'), $params);
$sql->execute();

$result = $sql->get_result();

}
```

Comment: OK, the code it self worked with no error but it return only the results of last word!!

Comment: It worked when I use `array_push($params, $search_word);` instead of `$params[]=& $search_word;`

Comment: And I got this warning `PHP Warning:  Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference`

Comment: Instead `array_push($params, $search_word);` please use `array_push($params, &$search_word);`